# Code analysis for android projects in Teamcity

Tags: intellij-idea, teamcity, code-analysis, lint, static-code-analysis

I have a gradle based android studio project. I have installed IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE . Now  I want to check code quality using a command. Is this possible? The real question is whether you can do code analysis to a completed project using IntelliJ IDEA 14 CE. Please give a solution.

**EDIT**

If it's not possible is there any other tool available for code analysis which can be operated using a shell command. I require command based code checking which will make my job easier when I integrate a project with the continuous integration server(TeamCity).

Comment: Does this code analysis tool have run from the command line?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: I prefer that so that reports can be generated any time as easy as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lint is a very good option for code inspection. Just do the following

```
cd PATH_TO_PROJECT
chmod a+x gradlew
./gradlew lint
```

To avoid warnings from failing the build edit `build.gradle` file as below

```
android {
lintOptions {      
quiet false
abortOnError true
ignoreWarnings true
checkReleaseBuilds false
}
...
}
```

The errors will be obtained as an `html` and `xml` file in your output folder

Answer (score 1):

TeamCity has direct integration with IntelliJ IDEA inspections. If you check in your IntelliJ IDEA project into the version control system, you can add the "Inspections (IntelliJ IDEA)" build runner to your build configuration, and it will run the inspections without requiring you to set up the command line manually. See [the documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Inspections) for more information.

Comment: I checked that too..But the project does not have `.ipr` file ie; it is not an intelliJidea project. When i worked on this I found that inspections can be done through command line and the report can be generated. How to integrate intelliJ idea inspections to my android project.Is it possoble to do that to an existing gradle based android studio project.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Please find the comment above and help me with a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use detekt which generates checkstyle formatted xml that can be parsed by TeamCity.
https://github.com/detekt/detekt